# Ajax request within partial view loaded through another Ajax request does not work properly in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Following is the exact scenario in my ASP.NET MVC application:

The parent page is having 3 tabs, and following javascript is written to bind click event to each of the tabs:

Each function invokes a controller action (specified in the data-url attribute), and renders the result in the partial view which is expected to be displayed within "ContactMainContainer" div.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ContactTabs a').on('click', function () {
        var dr = $(this).closest('li');
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        if (url != undefined && url != '') {
            var projectDetailTabModel = $("#ContactID").val();
            $('#successDiv').hide();
            $('#errorDiv').hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: getUrlWithTabId(url),
                data: projectDetailTabModel,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#ContactMainContainer').html(result);
                },
                error: function (errMessage) {
                    if (errMessage != null && errMessage.length > 0) {
                        $("#errorDiv").show();
                        $("#errorText").html(errMessage);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Contents of one of the partial view is built using javascripts (mostly ajax calls). (I am unable to put the whole javascript here as it is a client project and confidentiality agreement, and the javascript library is too large to place here).

The issue is that when a user navigates to that particular tab (having Ajax call), it takes a long time to execute and render the result. But after that if user clicks on any other tab the browser stucks and hangs for infinitely.

This issue is only in IE11, and works very well in all other browsers (Chrome, firefox, and all).

Could anyone please suggest what could be the reason?

Comment: Does IE11 throw any error in the console? Would help to see what `getUrlWithTabId(url)` does.

Comment: No, IE 11 doesn't report any error. the function getUrlWIthTabId(url) just builds URL and appends TabId to make unique URL for each tab in the browser. While debugging, I could see this URL to be correct, and it also renders output but takes more time than usual. And after that, clicking any other tab just hangs the browser.

Comment: Care to explain why this question was downvoted? To downvoter - It wont make you less superior if you take a minute to explain. If you can't, then dont just downvote straight-away. I deserve some sort of discussions/ solutions from the experts here with the amount of efforts I had put in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a caching issue and IE is well known for caching. You need to make sure in your Ajax call to set the catching as false

***Setting the cache property in an AJAX call***

```
$.ajax(url, {
    dataType: 'json',
    cache : false,
    //Other things ...
}
```

I prefer to use **`cache buster`** in the request URL, that is adding the current timestamp as parameter, so that it cant be cached

Comment: I have tried with "cache: false" option, but the same result.

Comment: Please remove cahce before checking ;) can u also check in the developer tools in IE6, and find whether the request is being made when u click and the page hangs ?

Comment: page doesn't get loaded in IE 6/ 7.. Lots of java script errors for obvious reasons, as the website is having all new libraries and frameworks :(

Comment: but you posted question about IE 11 mate. does it works now in IE 11 ?

Comment: I thought - by "can u also check in the developer tools in IE6" you wanted me to check in IE 6! sorry, that's misunderstanding... However, this does not work in IE 11. Same result. Hangs